# How to change span text in text block?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How to change `span` text e.g, if I have a XAML code like this:

```
<text block x:name="tb1">
  <span x:name="span1">this is the first span/>
  <span x:name="span2">this is the span I want to                change</span.>
</text>
```

So how do I change the second span without ramps with the first?

I tried codes like:

```
span1.innerXAML="RANDOM TEXT"
```

But they didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Run` to display the text in `Span`. Here is a code sample.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Span>
        <Run Name="MyText1" Text="My Text 1"/>
    </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

To change value

```
MyText1.Text = "Changed Text";
```

To learn more about `TextBlock`: [Text​Block Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock)